# Hierarchy in sql table at 100th place

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL table looks like this

| unit_number | name | party_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1700 | Facilities | 000018727 |
| 1800 | Human Resource | 000018728 |
| 1801 | PRO | 000092293 |
| 1802 | Human Resource | 000092294 |
| 1803 | Recruitment | 000092295 |
| 1804 | Learning & Development | 000092296 |
| 1805 | Administration | 000100783 |
| 1900 | Information Technology | 000018729 |
| 1901 | Information Technology | 000092297 |
| F&B | F&B | 000045759 |
| PRODUCT. | Product | 000103719 |

I want to make a hierarchy structure of the above table where 1700,1800,1900...(at 100th place) are at level 1, while subsequent 1801, 1802 at level 2, level 3 resp.

What should be the query for that? I want to add a level column to the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the dense rank function as the following:

To make the not number values appear at the bottom of the hierarchy level use the following:

```
select *,
  dense_rank() over 
  (order by 
      case 
        when try_cast(unit_number as int) is null 
         then 1 else 0 
      end,
      isnull(try_cast(unit_number as int),99) % 100
  ) as h_level
from table_name
```

To make the not number values appear at the top of the hierarchy level use the following:

```
select *,
  dense_rank() over 
  (order by 
      case 
        when try_cast(unit_number as int) is null 
         then 0 else 1
      end,
      isnull(try_cast(unit_number as int),1) % 100
  ) as h_level
from table_name
```

And if you want to consider the not number values to be in level 1 along with the (1700, 1800, ...), try this:

```
select *,
  dense_rank() over 
  (order by isnull(try_cast(unit_number as int),0) % 100) as h_level
from table_name
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/l1GtW_By)

Comment: when unit_number is not int then give level as 1, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, just change `when try_cast(unit_number as int) is null then 1 else 0` to  `when try_cast(unit_number as int) is null then 0 else 1` , I will update the answer according to this

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    my_new_col = 1
WHERE  unit_number LIKE '%00'
```

Then repeat with both values increased.

It can be done with a more complicated command in one `UPDATE` and some string manipulation and type casting, but it sounds like this will be a one-time operation so I don't see a lot of value in trying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the modulo operator:

```
/* Start Demo Data */
DECLARE @Units TABLE (Unit_Number NVARCHAR(10), Name NVARCHAR(50), Party_Number NVARCHAR(10), HierarchyLevel NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Units (Unit_Number, Name, Party_Number) VALUES
('1700',      'Facilities            ', '000018727'),
('1800',      'Human Resource        ', '000018728'),
('1801',      'PRO                   ', '000092293'),
('1802',      'Human Resource        ', '000092294'),
('1803',      'Recruitment           ', '000092295'),
('1804',      'Learning & Development', '000092296'),
('1805',      'Administration        ', '000100783'),
('1900',      'Information Technology', '000018729'),
('1901',      'Information Technology', '000092297'),
('F&B',     'F&B'                   , '000045759'),
('PRODUCT.','Product'               , '000103719')
/* End Demo Data */

UPDATE @Units
   SET HierarchyLevel = COALESCE((TRY_CAST(Unit_Number AS INT) % 100),0) + 1
  FROM @Units

SELECT *
  FROM @Units
```

```
Unit_Number Name                    Party_Number    HierarchyLevel
------------------------------------------------------------------
1700        Facilities              000018727       1
1800        Human Resource          000018728       1
1801        PRO                     000092293       2
1802        Human Resource          000092294       3
1803        Recruitment             000092295       4
1804        Learning & Development  000092296       5
1805        Administration          000100783       6
1900        Information Technology  000018729       1
1901        Information Technology  000092297       2
F&B         F&B                     000045759       1
PRODUCT.    Product                 000103719       1
```

Modulo returns the remainder after dividing a value by the value specified. In this case we want to know what the remainder is after dividing Unit_Number by 100. In order to start with a 1-indexed value as you requested we then add 1 to that.

100 returns 0, + 1: 1
101 returns 1, + 1: 2

We then just use this to update the HeierarchyLevel column.

When you're providing demo data for questions like this, it's very helpful to do so in an easily reusable format so folks can quickly work on your problem.